# Click button in Selenium2Library takes 5 minutes

Tags: jenkins, robotframework, selenium2library

I have in my script `Wait Until Keyword Succeeds  25  1   click element ${loginButton}` and it is running on Jenkins. In report it says that it took five minutes than it failed. Can I assume that it means some problem on server site? And why it it took so long time and didn't failed earlier? Also what is advantage of `click button` over `click element`?
Thank you for your answers.

I am using Selenium2Library 1.8.0

Answer (score 0):

The error message only highlights that it tried to successfully click the element 25 times (once ever second for 25 seconds) but failed on every attempt. The likely scenarios:

1. The reference to the element is correct, and the application (Page) is incorrect.
2. The reference is incorrect and the application (Page) state is correct.
3. Both are correct but the average load time is more than 25 seconds.

Without knowing the content of `${loginButton}`and the actual code of the page it is impossible to determine which of the three scenarios applies.

Comment: Thank you for reply. I have similar taste case and it has 80 instead of 25 times and it also takes 5 minutes. Button is correct and also page should be. I can run this script successfully. This error usually happens in the morning when it is set to run. So can I assume it is 3. case? And what it exactly means? Server is too slow?